# Space After Semicolons?

Tags: grammar

Should there be spaces after a semicolon in a sentence? For example:

"...minimum/standard requirements for a base diploma;there has been..."

or

"...minimum/standard requirements for a base diploma; there has been..."

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  Generally a space is needed after punctuation and before the start of a new word, the exceptions being the beginning of an enclosed pair such as (parentheses) and "quote" marks.  Compound word separators such as hyphens - and slashes "and/or" are also exceptions to using a space.

Comment: Should the continuing sentence start with a capital letter, or stay as lowercase?

Comment: after a semicolon, always use lowercase (unless the first word is ordinarily in uppercase) -- just like you would after a comma

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Is this same in the case of a dash, as in: "...the upmost importance in this particular subject–it is...". Should there be a space? What about capitalisation of the following sentence after the dash?

Comment: My personal opinion is that spaces around a dash (when distinguished from a hyphen) enhance the readability, and I prefer to use them.  However, the most commonly accepted form of typography generally avoids use of spaces around a long dash (em-dash or en-dash).